# Here maps - Am I able to search for business using offline map data?

Tags: applications

as title.

I want to know if I can still search for business and not just street data while offline. For those instances when I'm out of coverage. Thanks :)

Comment: Yes i think so. When i had it it worked nice and i could search stores.

Comment: Why not simply switch to airplane mode and try?

Comment: I don't have the app yet and with my slow internet and data limits, I cannot easily try and download the app + the offline maps which around 1GB+ for me. :)